# Cannot install XPages Extension Library into Domino Designer

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am needing to install the XPages Extension Library into my Domino Designer.  I have downloaded it from openNTF and tried following the directions on the TLCC site [here](http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/pages/extension-lib)

When I get to the step to Install new software and to "Add Folder Location", I select the correct folder and after clicking OK, I get no errors, however the update site is NOT in the location list.

[image]

If I select a different folder with out that doesn't contain 'site.xml' then I get an error.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this, or how to get around it. I need to install the extension library for the sole purpose to get an old project to compile so I can deploy a one line code change.

The ExtLib version I am trying to install is 901v00_11.2014. The reason I picked this old version was because the application was developed in that timeframe.

The Designer version is Designer 10.0.1.

The update site was downloaded from openntf.org.

Why I need to install the ExtLib:
[image]

I am trying to compile an old XPages app and getting the error show in the screenshot.

Comment: Note:  I have no idea what BuildManagerUpdateSite is. I am purposing installing an older version to match was the older XPages app uses

Comment: A little more info is required: Designer version, extlib version, log entries. Where did you encounter BuildManagerUpdateSite?

Comment: Hi stwissel, hope you are doing well.  I was hoping you would see this.  I updated the question above.  I am not sure what log entries you mean though.

Comment: I am thinking I will try a newer version of the ExtLib to see if that works.  I am just needing it to get a successful build so I can deploy a one line change.

Comment: What errors are you seeing? I’m pretty sure that standard Domino Designer includes a version of ext. library

Comment: Hi Per, hope this finds you well.  I have updated the question to show why I need to Install the ExtLib.  I also need to install POI for XPages after I get this working.

Comment: No errors, it is just won't show up in the location list, so I can't continue

Answer (score 3):

The error message says that Designer is missing the extlibx library (and not the standard extlib library). So I suggest that you install the [ExtLibX library](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20ExtLibX).